# PDF.JS failing with invalid URL?

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf.js

I am trying to extract the text from PDFs online. I use PDF.JS and I have something along these lines:

```
import { getDocument } from "pdfjs-dist";

function getTextFromPdf(url){
  var pdf = getDocument(url);
  return pdf.then(function(pdf) {
    var maxPages = pdf.pdfInfo.numPages;
    var countPromises = [];
    for (var j = 1; j <= maxPages; j++) {
      var page = pdf.getPage(j);    
      var txt = "";
      countPromises.push(page.then(function(page) {
        var textContent = page.getTextContent();
        return textContent.then(function(text){ 
          return text.items.map(function (s) { return s.str; }).join('');
        });
      }));
    }
    return Promise.all(countPromises).then(function (texts) {
      return texts.join('');
    });
  });
}
```

which I call with something like:

```
getTextFromPdf('https://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf').then(function (text) {
    console.log(text);
},
function (reason) {
    console.log(`Failed with ${reason}`);
});
```

This fails at `var pdf = getDocument(url)` with `Error handling response: Error: Invalid PDF url data: either string or URL-object is expected in the url property.`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The `getDocument` function doesn't return a promise, it's a `_PDFDocumentLoadingTask` instance, and it has a promise property you can use as a normal promise. You may need to set `GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc` before call `getDocument`, or else it may cause below error:

[image]

It may still can't work as expected, if so, check the developer tool to verify whether has CORS request error.

[image: CORS Error]

##### Minimum code snippet to test using [Vite.js](https://vitejs.dev/)

```js
import { getDocument, GlobalWorkerOptions } from "pdfjs-dist";
import workerSrc from 'pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.js?url';

GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = workerSrc;

function getTextFromPdf(url){
  var pdf = getDocument(url);
  console.log("getTextFromPdf", pdf);
  return pdf.promise.then(function(pdf) {
    var maxPages = pdf.pdfInfo.numPages;
    var countPromises = [];
    for (var j = 1; j <= maxPages; j++) {
      var page = pdf.getPage(j);    
      var txt = "";
      countPromises.push(page.then(function(page) {
        var textContent = page.getTextContent();
        return textContent.then(function(text){ 
          return text.items.map(function (s) { return s.str; }).join('');
        });
      }));
    }
    return Promise.all(countPromises).then(function (texts) {
      return texts.join('');
    });
  });
}

getTextFromPdf('https://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf').then(function (text) {
  console.log(text);
  },
                                                                         function (reason) {
  console.log(`Failed with ${reason}`);
});
```